# How to add additional condition while checking whether the guest allowed to checkout or not ( isAllowedGuestCheckout()) in magento 2

Tags: checkout, magento2.2.2

I have created custom module to check additional condition while checking isAllowedGuestCheckout().Please provide me a solution

Answer (score 0):

Just make an after plugin for this method: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Helper/Data.php#L358

Here's a tutorial on how to make a plugin:
http://www.coolryan.com/magento/2016/01/21/plugins-in-magento-2/